# Email clients and browser don't consider deeplink as a clickable link

Tags: android, html, react-native, deep-linking, android-deep-link

We are trying to implement email confirmation in our app, but emails received by users dont have a clickable link they are receiving only text, as a learned in some places it's because they are removing the href because they're not considering it as a link.
our deeplink = `ourApp://CONFIRM_EMAIL_SCREEN?conirm_token=1234`

This our solution in android part

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="ourApp" />
</intent-filter>
```

Could someone please show some solutions, in backend or frontend, how can we deal with that ? our app is published in google play store, can we generate links like https://ourpp.confirm-email-screen.com ???